# How to grey out a particular section of a div when dragging another div over it using javascript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

http://experiments.muditameta.com/whichTriangle/

The functionality shown in the above link is to be achieved on dragging an element. Also, without using whichtriangle.js  plugin. Can this be achieved ?? Is there a way to solve this??

Comment: the link you have given, doesnt have another div dragging..but it has a mousehover

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jQuery UI Droppable.

You can check the demo here : [jQuery UI Photo Manager](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)

From your question, it looks like you want to have the div highlighted when the item reaches the droppable div.

But this demo colors the droppable div yellow as soon as you start dragging the item.

But still, it can be a good start for what you want to achieve.